# referencing columns - pgAdmin 4

Tags: sql, postgresql

When using the Query tool in pgAdmin4 for Postgres, I have to use double quotes "" if I want to reference columns in a query.

Can this be altered so that double quotes are not needed? I have my database setup in Manjaro yet I have the same setup on another system in Ubuntu and I am 99% sure that on that install, I do not need to use double quotes in the query tool.

Does anyone know if this is a setting that could be amended as it is really annoying having to put all column references into double quotes all the time

This simple select query fails:

```
SELECT saleDate,qty,saleAmount FROM sales
```

and I get the following error:

```
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "sales.saleDate". SQL state: 42703 Character: 8
```

Yet this works fine:

```
SELECT "saleDate", "qty", "saleAmount" FROM sales
```

Would just be nice not to have to reference every single column with ""'s

Comment: That simple SELECT query fails because you use UPPERcase. Just don't use UPPERcase and you won't have these problems.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean the Upper case SELECT and FROM statements? If so, even it I use these statements in lower case I get the exact same error

Comment: This is the problem: saleDate. That UPPER case D. Don't use names in uppercase, only in lower case. That means you should create a column saledate, not saleDate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to use double quotes for case sensitive identifiers or identifiers including special characters or that are reserved words.

Simply avoid using such identifiers when creating objects, then you don't need to double quote them later on.

The identifiers in the database don't need to be "pretty" after all. The presentation layer should handle that.

Comment: For some reason I have to use double quotes for every single column reference. Even when all columns are lower case and I only run a basic Select query pulling in two columns such as columns called 'qty' or 'transdate' from just a single table. So I can only assume there is a setting somewhere making me have to do this. It does not make me use double quotes in my Ubuntu version. Just cannot see where the setting could be

Comment: @PaulHarper: [Edit] your question and post a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statement for such a table along with the query you use.

Comment: I have added a bit more info to help. The tables are all legacy tables, but the data types are just a date type in the 'saleDate' column with integer types in all other columns

Comment: @PaulHarper: You didn't show the `CREATE` statement as requested... Most likely it'll show that the columns are double quoted, like `"saleAmount"`. If you do that you need to always use quotes in the future. As I already wrote, just don't quote when creating objects to avoid being forced to quote every time in the future.

Comment: Ahh, that could be it. Didn't think of that being a possible issue. I did not create the tables and I have just been given them to pull some data from. But I will indeed check this in case this is the case.

Comment: I have just created myself a simple test table and I can now run a select query without the need for double quotes - so I can only assume that the sales table I am attempting to work with has indeed been setup using double quotes initially. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

[4.1.1. Identifiers and Key Words](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS):

> Quoting an identifier also makes it case-sensitive, whereas unquoted names are always folded to lower case. For example, the identifiers FOO, foo, and "foo" are considered the same by PostgreSQL, but "Foo" and "FOO" are different from these three and each other. (The folding of unquoted names to lower case in PostgreSQL is incompatible with the SQL standard, which says that unquoted names should be folded to upper case. Thus, foo should be equivalent to "FOO" not "foo" according to the standard. If you want to write portable applications you are advised to always quote a particular name or never quote it.)